# JAGS burn-in phase takes ZERO time?

Tags: bayesian, bugs, jags

My breath was taken away by this. I tried to run my JAGS model with different number burn-in samples but it still takes the same amout of time!!

```
n.iter    n.burnin    time   saved iterations per chain
 2000         1000     66s                         1000
 5000         4000     64s                         1000
20000        19000     62s                         1000
```

`n.chains` was 2 and `n.thin` was 1. So in each of the 3 model runs, I had different burn-in period, but the same second stage (`n.iter - n.burnin`, i.e. 1000 iterations per chain). All 3 models run for the same period of time!!! Does this mean that the burn-in phase takes zero time?

This is really a strange result, doesn't correspond to how I supposed the MCMC works. I thought that the burn-in phase is exactly the same computation process as the second stage, with the only difference that the samples are discarded.

I have used [R2jags::jags](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/R2jags/docs/jags2) function to run JAGS.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. Are you sure it's not a problem with your timer?

I prefer using rjags or dclone packages, but running this R2Jags example code:

```
library(R2jags)
# data
J <- 8.0
y <- c(28.4,7.9,-2.8,6.8,-0.6,0.6,18.0,12.2)
sd <- c(14.9,10.2,16.3,11.0,9.4,11.4,10.4,17.6)


jags.data <- list("y","sd","J")
jags.params <- c("mu","sigma","theta")
jags.inits <- function(){
  list("mu"=rnorm(1),"sigma"=runif(1),"theta"=rnorm(J))
}


schoolsmodel <- function() {
  for (j in 1:J){   # J=8, the number of schools
    y[j] ~ dnorm (theta[j], tau.y[j]) # data model:  the likelihood
    tau.y[j] <- pow(sd[j], -2)  # tau = 1/sigma^2
  }
  for (j in 1:J){
    theta[j] ~ dnorm (mu, tau)  # hierarchical model for theta
  }
  tau <- pow(sigma, -2)   # tau = 1/sigma^2
  mu ~ dnorm (0.0, 1.0E-6)# noninformative prior on mu
  sigma ~ dunif (0, 1000) # noninformative prior on sigma
}

a <- list()
a[[1]] <- system.time(jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data,
inits=jags.inits, jags.params, n.chains = 2,
n.iter = 2000, n.burnin = 1000, n.thin = 1, model.file=schoolsmodel))
a[[2]] <- system.time(jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data,
inits=jags.inits, jags.params, n.chains = 2, 
n.iter = 5000, n.burnin = 4000, n.thin = 1, model.file=schoolsmodel))
a[[3]] <- system.time(jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data,
inits=jags.inits, jags.params, n.chains = 2, 
n.iter = 20000, n.burnin = 19000, n.thin = 1, model.file=schoolsmodel))
a[[4]] <- system.time(jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data,
inits=jags.inits, jags.params, n.chains = 2, 
n.iter = 200000, n.burnin = 200000-1000, n.thin = 1, model.file=schoolsmodel))
```

Gave me the following results:

```
>   a
    [[1]]
 user  system elapsed 
0.242   0.000   0.244 

    [[2]]
 user  system elapsed 
0.272   0.000   0.274 

    [[3]]
 user  system elapsed 
0.541   0.000   0.544 

    [[4]]
 user  system elapsed 
3.732   0.005   3.746
```

Which indicates everything is as expected.

Comment: wow, that's strange! You have two progress bars, first one for burn-in and the second one for second stage, but I am completely missing the burn-in one! Despite of the fact that burn-in is set! Don't know what is going on.

Comment: This also happen in the code above? Might be a problem with R2Jags not passing the burn-in to Jags? What about using package rjags?

Comment: Nope, in your code I get two progress bars, but not in my code!

Comment: Odd indeed, as the manual states `If n.burnin is 0, jags() will run 100 iterations for adaption.`, then even with no burn.in set, you should get the progress bar. So I don't know why you don't see the burn-in progress bar.

Comment: I examined the issue in detail and [got the answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90492/5509)! If you just change `dunif` to `dgamma(0.01, 0.01)`, you will start to observe the problem :-) See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90492